# convert to HH;MM:SS in active reports

Tags: sql, activereports

I have a table with a column, TotalTime that is an Integer value in seconds.

In Active reports I want to display it in HH:MM:SS format.

Thanks!

also editing it in here comments not giving me enough space =-)

```
numberVar Seconds := {xxxx};
numberVar Hours := Truncate(Seconds / 3600);    
numberVar Minutes := Truncate((Seconds - (Hours*3600))/ 60);    

if (Hours > 0) then
ToText(Hours, "0") + ":" + ToText(Minutes, "00") + ":" + ToText(Seconds - (Hours*3600) - (Minutes*60), "00")
else
"0:" + ToText(Minutes, "00") + ":" + ToText(Seconds - (Hours*3600) - (Minutes*60), "00")
```

Comment: you want to request that format from your web server through a query?

Comment: no i would like to do it through a formula orsomething resembling this numberVar Seconds := 
numberVar Hours := Truncate(Seconds / 3600);    
numberVar Minutes := Truncate((Seconds - (Hours*3600))/ 60);    
if (Hours > 0) then
ToText(Hours, "0") + ":" + ToText(Minutes, "00") + ":" + ToText(Seconds - (Hours*3600) - (Minutes*60), "00")
else\0:" + ToText(Minutes, "00") + ":" + ToText(Seconds - (Hours*3600) - (Minutes*60), "00")that's taken from crystal reports to convert it there i want to do it in active reports not in sql or the stored proc....

Comment: that script was from crystal reports and im trying to convert to active reports and cant see a flied or something to put that formula in or something similar

Answer (score 1):

In the Format event of the section containing the textbox you want to display this value in, use code like the following:

```
 TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds); //Assuming "seconds" comes from a ActiveReport.Fields value or from  the Value property of a textbox in the report?
 theTextbox.Text = interval.ToString("c");
```

See the MSDN docs For more information on [FromSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx) and the ["c" format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx).